# PDF of rounded normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am using a distance sensor which generates data with noise. The noise follows a normal distribution centered at 0, with known variance. So, the sensor produces:

$S = d + W$, where $d$ is the real distance and $W\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ is a random variable

However, I have no direct access to $S$. Due to limitations of the communication protocol, the data is rounded to the nearest hundredth. So what I know is:

$S' = round(S)$, where $round$ rounds to the nearest hundredth

So:

$S' = round(d+W)$

The error of $S'$ is defined as:

$E=round(d+W)-d$

Which can be simplified as:

$E=round(X)-d$, $\quad$ where $X\sim \mathcal{N}(d,\sigma^2)$

My question is: Is there a way of deriving the PDF of the error $E$?

Note: I've read an article by A. R. Tricker called *Effects of Rounding on the Moments of a Probability Distribution*, where the author finds the first 2 moments of a normally distributed rounded random variable, but I don't see how I can get the PDF.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks! I provided context to the problem, and I hope it's now ok.

Comment: I guess you mean density for PDF, but please define acronyms bacause PDF can have other meanings.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you mean by "PDF". When we talk about PDFs, what we mean is "PDF with respect to some base measure". This will usually be the Lebesgue measure for continuous distributions and the counting measure for discrete distributions.

The reason that this is important is that in this continuous, Lebesgue measure setting, not every distribution has a corresponding density function. Your $E$ here is an example of that. To see this, firstly I'm going to assume that $d$ is already rounded to the nearest hundredth, for simplicity. Let's consider the point $0$.

The probability that $E$ outputs $0$ is the probability that $\text{round}(X)$ outputs $d$.

This is the equal to $\text{Pr}(d-0.005<X<d+0.005)$, which is obviously greater than $0$, as $X$ is normally distributed.

Now let's suppose that a real-valued function $f$ is a probability density function of $E$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure. What this would mean is the following:

$\text{Pr}(d-0.005<X<d+0.005) = \int_{\{0\}} f \; d\mu$, where $\mu$ denotes the Lebesgue measure. But $\{0\}$ is a nullset, so for all possible real-valued functions $f$, the right side of this equation is equal to $0$. We already stated above that the left side is strictly greater than $0$, so we have a contradiction, so such an $f$ cannot exist.

So if you're viewing $E$ as a continuous random variable and using the Lebesgue measure as your base measure, then $E$ has no corresponding probability density function.

---

Now let's instead consider the case where we consider $E$ to be a discrete random variable, and use the counting measure as our base measure. Now instead our equation looks as follows:

$\text{Pr}(d-0.005<X<d+0.005) = \int_{\{0\}} f \; d\mu$, where $\mu$ denotes the counting measure. This means that the right side of this equation evaluates to:

$\sum_{x \in \{0\}} f(x) = f(0)$.

This generalises to any point that's rounded to the nearest hundredth, so we see that on these points, $f$ is equal to the probability detailed on the left side of the equation (with $d$ replaced with $x+d$ for the point $x$ we're considering), which can be calculated easily using the CDF of the normal distribution. On points that aren't rounded to the nearest hundredth, the distribution isn't defined, as now we're looking at $E$ as a distribution on the set of real numbers that are rounded to the nearest hundredth. This part shouldn't be surprising, as this is simply a probability mass function.

---

Hopefully this helped, if anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wanted to know the probability density to compare two different errors ($E_1$ and $E_2$) and be able to say which one is more likely. Given that there is no correct way of defining the PDF, as you stated, how accurate would it be to consider $E=d+W+U-d=W+U$, where $W$ is the already defined normally distributed random variable centered at $0$, with $var=\sigma^2$; and $U$ is a uniformly distributed random variable between (-0.005 and 0.005) to replace the round function. Because in this way, I could obtain a PDF $f$=convolution of both individual PDFs.

Comment: Bear in mind you can consider the probability of the two different errors just using the CDF like I go through in the second part of my answer, where I talk about the discrete case.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean about considering $E = W + U$. This is quite a different distribution than your original $E$.

Comment: What I meant was replacing the rounding function with a uniformly distributed random variable between (-0.005 and 0.005). That was my only proposed change in order to be able to compute the PDF. In practice this works, but I don't know why it works. I wanted to understand the theory a bit better.